# How would I create an object, redirect to another controller to retrieve a value, then return to Create() action and set that value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I call Create() which puts an object in session and returns a view.  On that view is a button to "Add Item", which redirects to another controller, they select and item, and that id is returned to the first controller.  But I can't return to the same Create() method since that puts a new object in session, overwriting any changes they may have entered before clicking "Add Item".  How should I return to Create() when there may be some data already entered?

thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you have some separation of concerns issues going on.  Can you provide some additional detail on the roles of each of these controllers in question?  For instance, what is the responsibility of the controller which responds to the "Add Item" button?

Answer (score 0):

In the body of your Create() method you could check if there already is an item in session. If that is true then you can continue modifying that item. Otherwise this is a first request and only then should you put a new item in session.